# Error when converting json to python object

Tags: python, json

Í am trying to convert a json to a python object, but I keep getting this error and I don't know how to fix it.

This is the piece of code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

with urlopen("https://drive.google.com/file/d/13LFwPWd2jjMoWZqzBdXVpcewLNCLDg3Y/view") as response:
   source = response.read()

data = json.loads(source)
print(data.dumps(data), indent=2)
```

And this is the error I keep getting:

```
Exception has occurred: JSONDecodeError
Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  File "C:\Users\name\Documents\Analyse 3 assignment\PLS.py", line 15, in <module>
    data = json.loads(source)
```

I would really appreciate it if someone has the solution for me!

Comment: `Expecting value` tells me there is something wrong with the json string in `source`. Double check that the value in `source` is valid json (and possibly add it to your question in an edit)

Comment: That URL isn't a JSON file, it's a web page containing JSON in a text box.  Getting a direct link to Google Drive contents seems to be unnecessarily complicated - the only method I can find is to paste the URL into https://sites.google.com/site/gdocs2direct/